# Improve ALOS World 3D vertical precision with GPS data from fieldwork

Tags: dem, gps, 3d, mapping, satellite

I'm working on sport topo maps in Russia, european part (Pskov region, near Estonia/Latvia border), typical map is from 1 to 10 km2 in size. The most precise source of DEM for generating relief lines is ALOS World 3D (or may be i'm mistaken?). I wish to achieve relief lines with 5m step, and usually they are made through long-term fieldwork, but first i'm trying to generate base map with maximum available precision.

Is it possible to (slightly) improve quality of ALOS DEM, having some GPS tracks from territory survey? I'm using Garmin Dakota with barometr.

It's not possible to get LIDAR data or buy precise satellite data, because it's non-profit, enthusiasts project - we can't spent thousands of dollars for the data.

Comment: How much of an area are you talking about?  Is it possible to use drone imagery and Structure from Motion software to generate a new surface model?

Comment: In general, yes, we can use a drone, it's a various areas from 1 to 10 km2 each (usually 2-3). But there are dense forest, and surface model will be of low precision.